Is swap storage a solution for a not fixable memory leak?
I have a database service, which needs much more memory than expected. I do not want to state wich database is used, because I do not want answers for this specific database. I've tried already every common hint, some uncommon and used different tools for the database to analyse memory usage. I could not find the origin of the high memory usage.
The service is expected to use around 40GB of RAM on every server in a production cluster. On starting the service and on testing setups, the amount and configured limits are as expected. But in production, the service slowly allocates more and more memory.
The setup is a cluster of virtual machines running on Ubuntu LTS. The current solution is to raise the memory of every virtual machine to handle the memory usage. The amount of RAM is sized to handle the raised usage until the regular update windows with restarts. Though this solution is working, it is very expensive and it is not an ideal solution.
A restart resets the memory usage. The problem of the cluster is, that it is difficult and risky to automate an unattended restart every night. An attended restart would be as expensive as the memory raise.
Usually swap space is not recommended on the database system, some documentation recommends a swappiness setting of zero. If active data is swapped in production, it might slow down the database up to the point of an unexpected downtime. Though with a possible memory leak and if there are unused memory pages, an active swap storage might reduce costs of the setup without reducing performance.
Since the memory usage could not be reproduced outside of production, a swap setup could be tested only in production and the test could take weeks. That could be very risky and my intention is to reduce the risk.
I have very limited knowledge about swap settings aside from setting "swappiness". I am interested in ways to analyse, if a swap would help in this setup to reduce costs. Is there a way to monitor memory pages (like "inactive memory" from LC_ALL=c vmstat -s) for how long they are not used? Are there settings to optimize swap usage aside from "swappiness?

The correct approach is to identify and resolve the cause of the memory leak. For example, if it's SQL Server on a Windows platform it will use all the available memory bar a tiny amount of the OS - it assumes it's got everything else. You can adjust this with a tuning parameter. There may be something similar in your scenario and without knowing the detail of the database all you're going to get here is answers to sticky tape over a problem that might not even be a problem in the first place

You are right and your described way is the solution we tried the last 6 month. I am certainly not happy to search for a solution like this. Please assume we are experts with this kind of database with 20+ years of experience and this incident will certainly lead to a strategy changing our database setup.

May I suggest that you don't withold the database product but you summarise what you've done, so that we can see the reason you're trying to find this work-around. If you had all the answers you wouldn't need to be posting here.

What type of storage are you proposing to place swap on? SSD/NVMe, HDD, SAN...?

Swap will benefit you if memory accesses are clustered together rather than spread across the entire virtual memory space

Have you considered staggered restarts, maybe 25% of your estate each night rather than all machines? Or does your database system not work like that? Thinking about mitigating unexpected restart failures during unattended hours vs overall availability

Cloud based setup, storage is documented as network based with 10 Gigabit Ethernet with SSDs for physical storage. Usually fast, but bad neighborhood effects can happen. My guess is, that huge parts of the allocated memory is not used, though that is the the question, how to verify it? We could see unusual memory usage on the red-black-tree modul, an hypothesis is that during building indice on writes, part of the allocated memory is not freed. But we could not pin a query as source or create a reproducible example, to file a bug. On loadbalancing an instance as readonly, everything is fine.

Suggest enabling swap on one (?) machine, ideally one not impacting production. Use iostat and vmstat to collect statistics over your timing period (24hr?). Look to see how hard swap is being hit. If you can fire off a test suite do much the better
